# Convert JS array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to convert array:

```
['a', {java:'script'}, 'b', 23, 'c', ['qwe','rty']]
```

to object:

```
{a:{java:'script'}, b: 23, c: ['qwe','rty']}
```

Comment: Nothing you've written is valid JavaScript. It's very unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: You need to iterate the array and make odd index the keys and even index the values.

Comment: Do you mean `['a', { java: 'script' }, 'b', 23, 'c', ['qwe','rty']]` as input and `{ a: { java: 'script' }, b: 23, c: ['qwe', 'rty'] }`as output?

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9hm3o65). Next time remember to be more precise with the question and, first, provide your own solution to the problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const arr = ['a', { java:'script' }, 'b', 23, 'c', ['qwe','rty']]

const arr2obj = arr => {
  const obj = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1]
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(arr2obj(arr))
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pynw4mg9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['a', {java:'script'}, 'b', 23, 'c', ['qwe','rty']];

function arrToObj(arr) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(arrToObj(arr));
```